# How to extrude properly?

Tags: modeling

How do I extrude so that the circle moves inwards like at 13:04 in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xU_pi1UxISs? When I do it the vertices just move up.

[image: before]

[image: after]

Comment: Looks like you didn't select the center node. Perhaps you need to press a twice to select all?

Comment: [e]>[s] is what I've always done

Comment: @saclement99 - accept answers if they help, it lets other people know that an answer was useful and solved the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to enable your subsurf modifier by clicking the eye icon:

[image]

Right before then he enables the subsurf modifier, which causes the smooth subdivided interpolation of the mesh you are seeing.

Note that since the subsurf modifier is a *modifier*, you can enable it and disable it whenever you want without having to worry about doing it before or after various modeling operations. In other words, you *have* extruded it correctly, it just won't display the subdivided mesh until you enable the modifier.

Answer (score 0):

You would hit e s to extrude and then scale it using your current pivot point, which in your screenshot is correct as median point.